# Cannot get query results using RabDB

Tags: database

I use a very specialized database called RabDB (http://www.rabdb.org). From the project website:

> RabDB is a database created to explore the universe of the Rab family of small GTPases, key regulators of the Eukaryotic endomembrane system, predicted by the Rabifier classification pipeline in the sequenced eukaryotic genomes.

However, I run into a beginner problem: Upon submitting a query in the RabDB browser at http://www.rabdb.org/browser/profile, I only receive the following Response:

> Error #9999. Please look under the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy to solve: You need to implement a transformer called "tiny turbo changer". It's based on series 2 and can be used starting from 6+.
Hope that helps.
Thanks!

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Awesome to get a solution from the (presumed) author of RabDB!